# Find the sum from $k=1$ to $n$ for $x^{(k-1)}/k!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{(k-1)}}{k!}$

and let $E_2(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x}{({e^x-1})} & : x \ne 0\\
1 & : x=0
\end{array}
\right.$

Show that $|1 / E_2(x)-g_n(x)|\le \frac{|x|^ne^{|x|}}{(n+1)!}$

I guess that I need to start by finding the series for $g_n(x)$ but I don't know where to start with that...

Please help!

Comment: Is it $k+1$ or $k-1$? Please decide. Also, please use $ in the title.

Comment: $g_n(x)$ is already a series.

Comment: It is $k-1$ sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with $x\;g_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x-\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}-1$ since $e^x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

*Edit: now that Tim got it, I complete my answer.*
*I'd like to give credit to **Gio67** as he posted first a similar follow up.*

We have $\displaystyle{|x\;g_n(x)-e^x-1|=|\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}|\le\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^k}{k!}\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x|^{k-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}}$

Now we can re-index the sum:

$\displaystyle{|x\;g_n(x)-e^x-1|\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} |x|^k\overbrace{\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+n+1)!}}^{(*)}}\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^k}{k!}\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}e^{|x|}}{(n+1)!}$

$(*) :\quad\le \frac 1{k!}$ since $(i+n+1)>i$ for $i>0$ and for $i=0$ it is $1=0!$

Comment: haha, my hint had too many details! But I had already typed it by the time you posted your reply

Comment: @Gio67 That's why I upvoted it, but I would have done the same nevertheless, there are not zillion possibilities to follow up given the expected result fixed by OP. I'll put explicit credit in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find a formula for $g_n$. Follow zwim hint and use the fact that 
\begin{align}\frac1x \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)&=\frac1x \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=
\frac1x \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-n-1}}{k!}(n+1)!\\&
=
\frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{x^{l}}{(l+n+1)!}(n+1)!
\end{align} where $l=k-n-1$.
You will need to estimate the right had side in absolute values to get $e^{|x|}$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense mainly, except I don't understand why we must use absolute values for $|x^n|$ and $e^{|x|}$ (as well as the LHS). Is this because it could be complex?

Comment: The problem is with the two factorials on the right hand side. You will need to bound them in order to get $\frac1{l!}$ and so you will need absolute values since $x$ can be negative

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following how to go about that - what kind of bounds would you impose?. Please could you elaborate a bit? Thanks

Comment: you need to prove that $$\left\vert\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{x^{l}}{(l+n+1)!}(n+1)!\right\vert\le \sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{|x|^{l}}{l!}=e^{|x|}$$

Comment: Oh of course, I get it now. My excuse - its 3AM in Australia :D Thanks!